# Different settings for emacs -nw

Tags: emacs

I was wondering what to put in my .emacs file to have different settings depending on whether I run a normal emacs session or whether I run emacs in the terminal with `emacs -nw`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the variable `window-system-version` to tell if you are on a terminal. If this variable is `nil`, then it is terminal mode.

Example .emacs:

```
(when window-system-version
  ;; setup for graphic environment
)
```